# Are the hyperbolic functions universal for all negative Gaussian curvatures?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

Usually in hyperbolic geometry, a Gaussian curvature of $-1$ is assumed. However, if you imagine the surface of a pseudosphere with radius $\tfrac12$, then the gaussian curvature will become $-4$ per the formula $k = -1/r^2$ where $r$ is the radius of the pseudosphere.

Now, if I choose to map a triangle onto that surface, I assume that the triangle will have different angles and different area than the one on the pseudosphere of radius $1$.

Therefore, why do we only have the functions $\sinh,\,\cosh,\,\tanh$, that we've come to know, and not for other curvatures?

Comment: Just as the circular trig functions exist and have utility outside of *spherical geometry*, so too the hyperbolic trig functions exist and have utility outside of *hyperbolic geometry*. For trig *within* the geometries, the families work "as-is" for surfaces of Gaussian curvature $+1$ (sph) & $-1$ (hyp). For arbitrary curvature $\pm1/r^2$, we *do* have dedicated functions (for lengths; angles always use the standard circular functions (why?)): they're the standard functions *composed with division by $r$*; eg, $\sin(x/r)$, $\tanh(x/r)$, etc. Conveniently, this simple adjustment is all we need.